Coverity build in linux env (cmake project) is failing
I am working on implementing the static code analyzer for our linux env code base and I am facing NO FILES EMITTED issue in it.
These are the steps I followed:
I have linux version Coverity 2023.9.2. We use cmake to build our projects with “Ninja” as the build system. I have configured Coverity with various templates in “myConfig.xml” file so that I don’t miss any compiler. My project is in C++ and C#.
Below is the command how I configure our cmake project before cov-build capture.

*az73@lin*:**/usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Readers/out/install/WSL-GCC-Debug" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/mnt/d/microservices/repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" /mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Readers/CMakeLists.txt**

This is the cov-build command which I give while building the configured cmake project. (You can see that build is in progress without any issues)
*az73@lin*:**/mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Readers/build/WSL-GCC-Debug$ cov-build --dir cov-int --config /mnt/d/linux-coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-2023.9.2/bin/myConfig.xml /usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Readers/build/WSL-GCC-Debug --clean-first --config Debug**

Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2023.9.2 on Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64
Internal version numbers: 395a026bc9 p-2023.9-push-64


[1/1] Cleaning all built files...
Cleaning... 199 files.
[58/202] Linking CXX shared library OutputHelper/ClipperTableAccessor/libClipperTableAccessor.so
MSBuild version 17.7.6+77d58ec69 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Logging -> /mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Logging/bin/Debug/net6.0/Logging.dll
  Utilities -> /mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Utilities/bin/Debug/net6.0/Utilities.dll
  ClipperTableAccessor -> /mnt/d/microservices/InteropServices/src/Services/Modules/HxGN.PPM.Interop.Readers/build/WSL-GCC-Debug/OutputHelper/ClipperTableAccessor/net6.0/ClipperTableAccessor.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:42.74
[94/202] Building CXX object Readers/NavisworksReader/NavisworksFileReader/CMakeFiles/NavisworksFileReader.dir/NavisworksFileReader.cpp.o

And the error I have been facing is this:
**[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.**

When I tried for a sample cpp file which two issues, I could see that Coverity is able to capture it:
*az73@lin*:**/mnt/c/Users/ashaik2/Desktop$ cov-build --dir cov-int-samp --config /mnt/d/linux-coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-2023.9.2/bin/myConfig.xml g++ sample.cpp -o sample**

Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2023.9.2 on Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64
Internal version numbers: 395a026bc9 p-2023.9-push-64


Emitted 1 C/C++ compilation units (100%) successfully

1 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis

I am not sure why Coverity is unable to emit any files when I am trying at project level. I would like to know if I am missing anything.

I'd guess that your vcpkg toolchain is overriding the compiler set by coverity

what Alan wrote, and if that is the case, you may check the compile_commands.json to see how compiler is launched for each file? I guess cov-build should be there listed instead of mscc or what vcpkg is using. And do you configure it in clean build dir? Just to rule out any cmake cache issues, you can add --fresh to cmake configuration step when preparing ninja build recipes.

cov-build creates a file called build-log.txt in the intermediate directory.  Would you add that file, or a representative excerpt?  In particular there should be the compiler config at the top and EXECUTING lines corresponding to the compiler invocations during the build.

You might also want to run your cmake configure under cov-build too?

@Ped7g i have even tried configuring in the clean build dir and also tried with --fresh opt, no use though. coming to the compile_commands.json, this is how a sample command looks like: "command": "/usr/bin/cc -I/mnt/d/microservices/repos/vcpkg/buildtrees/libzip/src/a009075b9a-41a56dd033.clean/lib -I/mnt/d/microservices/repos/vcpkg/buildtrees/libzip/x64-linux-dbg -isy. i have configured with cc compiler and gave a try, still no use.
@ScottMcPeak, yes there's build-log.txt in the intermediate directory but I don't find it useful.

I'm asking that you include portions of the log file in your question, especially the compiler configs and the EXECUTING lines.  If I see the log file I can advise on what is likely wrong.

I understand it, thank you @ScottMcPeak. I have gone through the build-log and learned that the actual command during build is c++ -options file.cpp. c++ is an alias of g++ in linux env I guess. A cov-configure with c++ solved my problem and I can see cov-build emits files to get them analyzed. Thanks everone in the thread :)

I have gone through the build-log and learned that the actual command during build is c++ -options file.cpp. c++ is an alias of g++ in linux env I guess. A cov-configure with c++ solved my problem and I can see cov-build emits files to get them analyzed.
